# Java Maven Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven

I've just started to learn Java but have issues almost at every step...
At least I want to make [this super simple getting started tutorial](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) work (**from official Maven page**) :)

I've done every step like in this tutorial and have built the project but can't run it.

So, after `mvn package` I have `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` but when I'am trying to launch `jar` file by this command `java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App` an error occurs:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.app.App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.app.App
```

How to fix it?

**java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS**

**Apache Maven 3.6.0**

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Project structure is created automatically by this command as shown in the docs

```
my-app
 |-src
 |  |-main
 |     |-java
 |        |-com
 |           |-mycompany
 |              |-app
 |                 |-App.java
 |-pom.xml
 |-target
```

And the `App.java` code:

```
 package com.mycompany.app;

 /**
  * Hello world!
  *
 */
 public class App 
 {
     public static void main( String[] args )
     {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

And `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-test</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>maven-test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Also I had to add these lines to make work `mvn package` command:

```
<properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: if you are just starting to learn java, start by learning java on it's own. add maven later

Comment: I suggest you to write your code and compile it via javac command. later on ,when you increase your mindset and knowledge,you start to use frameworks ,libaries like maven etc.

Comment: @Stultuske, thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem. Furthermore I'am trying to repeat very simple example from official maven docs.

Comment: @mr.boris no, it might, however, avoid this kind of problems for you in the long run. this is like someone who just learned to walk after being paralyzed for his entire life saying: "I just tried to run 15 miles and my leg hurts".
Sure, you can massage the leg, but unless you build up and start at the beginning, that leg 'll hurt the next time as well.

Comment: @Stultuske, thank you for mentoring, but I have experience in programming generally. So, if some minor error occurs then should be some simple solution for it. All in all this issue is not about multithreading or concurrency. In my opinion solution for such issues should be in the first lines of Google searching but it isn't (especially if related to official docs). So, it's first wake-up call to me for keep on going with Java.

Comment: Broadly speaking I agree that starting simple is better, and avoiding something like Maven will probably give you a better initial experience with Java, however, as you've identified this is still a _pretty_ simple example, so I don't think it's a terrible way to start. My usual first step for debugging issues like this would be to check the generated JAR file, first, confirm that it exists in your `/target` directory and has the name you expect (likely), then, as it's just a zip file, you can unzip it and check that the contents match your project structure.

Comment: For what it's worth, following the steps you mention above (without reference to the tutorial) works perfectly for me, without setting the `properties` elements you mention. I suspect the problem is somewhere else... Maven/Java versions, perhaps?

Comment: do you run the `java ...` command from the project's main directory? Try a `jar -tf target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` from there to see what's inside the jar, to make sure the `App` class is in there with the right path

Comment: @Chirlo, thanks, this command doesn't work for me: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave, thank you for the answer. I use `11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS` Java version and  `3.6.0` for Apache Maven. I don't know why the same thing works for you but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-try with this 4 commnds:

```
> mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
> cd my-app
> mvn package
> java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for testing this sample. As for me I have an error on `mvn package` step.. `BUILD FAILURE` `Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.`. At least for this step I have to add `properties` to the `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your the output of the `jar` command, (the `NoSuchFileException` from the comments), it seems  you were running the `java` command from some directory other than that of the maven project. @Sgrillon's answer works because he changes directory to that of `my-app`, runs the `mvn package` command and then the `java` command from the same directory. Then the `target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is there (generated by maven)  and can be found by the `java` command to include it in its classpath (`-cp`) 
This is not a java or maven problem but an issue with the file's path.

**EDIT**: I just realized on your `pom.xml` that your artifact  was named `maven-test`

```
  <artifactId>maven-test</artifactId>
```

In this case, the jar would have been `target/maven-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` instead of `my-app...` and that's why neither `java` nor `jar` could find it.

Comment: Thanks, everything works now after removing current project and repeat all steps again despite that fact that I had to modify `properties` in `pom.xml` file a little bit for the right Maven compiler versioning. Actually, I tried to run `.jar` file from the same directory (from the root of the project), so that I have no clue why that error occurred

Comment: @Mr.boris, see my edit on the answer, did you  manually changed the artifactId on the pom.xml??

Comment: @Chirlo what would the artifactId change to from 'maven-test'. I am having the same issue

Comment: @Hana, not sure what you're asking. In this question, the OP had probably changed the `-DartifactId=my-app` parameter to `-DartifactId=maven-test` when creating the project, but did change it when calling `java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...`.